# Unresolved function or method "xxx" from Jest (23.5.0) in WebStorm (2018.2.3)

Tags: reactjs, webstorm, jestjs

I've been having an issue with Jest (23.5.0) and WebStorm (2018.2.3) intellisense lately. For all the Jest methods (e.g. `toHaveBeenCalledWith`, `toHaveLength`), I receive a `Unresolved function or method "xxx"` error.

I have `@types/jest` working in all of my projects except for my most recent one, which stopped working once I ejected from CRA.
Strangely enough, if I delete all my project's `node_modules`, the the intellisense on Jest works just fine - but as soon as I run `yarn install` the intellisense stops working and I get the `Unresolved function or method "xxx"` error. So I suspect one of my packages is causing `@types/jest` to stop working.

Screenshots of the problem:

[image: Jest error message]

[image: @types/jest in project libraries]

What I've tried:

- All the methods discussed in the [JetBrains forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000357324-Get-rid-of-Unresolved-function-method-variable-warning-in-Jest-test-files?page=1#community_comment_360000121219) regarding this issue
- This [alternate workaround](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/fix-element-is-not-imported-jest-describe-it-expect-in-webstorm-aaf8c29ae3c2)
- Invalidating Webstorm's cache and restarting
- Reinstalling packages after deleting lock files

My project's setup:

- My WebStorm version is 2018.2.3
- My `package.json` looks as follows:

  ```
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "0.18.0",
        "classnames": "2.2.6",
        "dashjs": "2.9.0",
        "get-countries-info": "1.2.1",
        "lodash": "4.17.10",
        "moment": "2.22.2",
        "nuka-carousel": "4.3.5",
        "prop-types": "15.6.2",
        "querystringify": "2.0.0",
        "react": "16.4.2",
        "react-custom-scrollbars": "4.2.1",
        "react-dom": "16.4.2",
        "react-icons-kit": "1.1.7",
        "react-image-fallback": "8.0.0",
        "react-lottie": "1.2.3",
        "react-player-controls": "0.5.21",
        "react-redux": "5.0.7",
        "react-router-dom": "4.3.1",
        "react-select": "2.0.0",
        "react-toastify": "3.3.4",
        "redux": "4.0.0",
        "redux-promise": "0.6.0",
        "redux-thunk": "2.3.0",
        "uuid-validate": "0.0.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "autoprefixer": "9.1.5",
        "babel-core": "6.26.3",
        "babel-eslint": "9.0.0",
        "babel-jest": "23.4.2",
        "babel-loader": "7.1.2",
        "babel-preset-react-app": "3.1.2",
        "babel-runtime": "6.26.0",
        "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
        "chalk": "2.4.1",
        "css-loader": "1.0.0",
        "dotenv": "6.0.0",
        "dotenv-expand": "4.2.0",
        "enzyme": "3.6.0",
        "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.4.0",
        "enzyme-matchers": "6.0.4",
        "eslint": "5.5.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "3.0.1",
        "eslint-config-react-app": "2.1.0",
        "eslint-loader": "2.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.50.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "2.14.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jest": "21.22.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.1.1",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "2.6.2",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "7.11.1",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
        "file-loader": "2.0.0",
        "fs-extra": "7.0.0",
        "generate-react-code": "1.3.0",
        "husky": "0.14.3",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
        "jest": "23.5.0",
        "jest-enzyme": "6.0.4",
        "jest-mock-console": "0.4.0",
        "lint-staged": "7.2.2",
        "moxios": "0.4.0",
        "node-sass-chokidar": "1.3.3",
        "npm-run-all": "4.1.3",
        "object-assign": "4.1.1",
        "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.1.0",
        "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
        "promise": "8.0.1",
        "prettier": "1.14.2",
        "raf": "3.4.0",
        "react-dev-utils": "5.0.2",
        "redux-devtools-extension": "2.13.5",
        "redux-logger": "3.0.6",
        "resolve": "1.8.1",
        "style-loader": "0.23.0",
        "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "0.11.5",
        "url-loader": "1.1.1",
        "webpack": "3.12.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "2.11.3",
        "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.0.3",
        "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.4"
    },
    "lint-staged": {
        "*.js": [
            "prettier --write",
            "eslint --fix",
            "git add"
        ],
        "*.scss": [
            "prettier --write",
            "git add"
        ]
    },
    "babel": {
        "presets": [
            "react-app"
        ]
    }
  ```
- My `eslintrc.json` file looks as follows:

  ```
    {
        "env": {
            "browser": true,
            "es6": true,
            "jest/globals": true,
            "jest": true,
            "node": true
        },
        "globals": {
            "process": true,
            "localStorage": true,
            "customScrollHandler": true,
            "customOnScrollEvent": true
        },
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "prettier",
            "eslint:recommended",
            "plugin:react/recommended",
            "plugin:jest/recommended",
            "plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended"
        ],
        "parserOptions": {
            "ecmaVersion": 6,
            "sourceType": "module",
            "ecmaFeatures": {
                "jsx": true
            }
        },
        "plugins": ["react", "jest", "prettier", "jsx-a11y"],
        "settings": {
            "react": {
                "version": "16.4.2"
            }
        },
        "rules": {
            "class-methods-use-this": "off",
            "semi": ["error", "always"],
            "no-console": ["error", { "allow": ["warn", "error"] }],
            "react/jsx-handler-names": "off",
            "import/no-namespace": "off",
            "import/namespace": "off",
            "import/prefer-default-export": "off",
            "import/default": "off",
            "react/prefer-stateless-function": "off",
            "react/jsx-curly-brace-presence": ["error", { "props": "never", "children": "ignore" }],
            "jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events": "off",
            "jsx-a11y/media-has-caption": "off",
            "jsx-a11y/no-static-element-interactions": "off",
            "jsx-a11y/label-has-for": "off",
            "jsx-a11y/no-noninteractive-element-interactions": "off",
            "jsx-a11y/href-no-hash": "off",
            "jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": "off"
        }
    }
  ```

Comment: please provide a code snippet that shows up the issue

Comment: Sure! I've added some snapshots illustrating the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`expect` is resolved to `window.expect` in `node_modules/react-custom-scrollbars/test.js`, causing the issue. You can exclude this file from indexing by marking it as plain text (**Mark as plain text** in file right-click menu) - this should solve the issue

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much!! I'm out of the office at the moment, but I'll check it as soon as I'm back - I'll keep you posted.

Comment: `ctrl+click` on `expect` to see what definition it's resolved to:)

Comment: Genius! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 11):

In Webstorm :
Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries, press Download..., select 'jest' from the list of available stubs, press Download and Install

[Source](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000357324-Get-rid-of-Unresolved-function-method-variable-warning-in-Jest-test-files)

Comment: the link isnt working

Comment: Link updated, thx for feedback

Answer (score 1):

In my case (using "react": "^18.2.0", yarn 3.6.3 and Typescript) the issue was with missing import

```
import 'jest';
```

in `setupTest.ts`

After I added  the line, web storm started seeing all Jest methods

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers, but following worked for me

1. I had intel compatible intellij installed on my mac(apple-chip), replaced it with apple chip compatible intellij.
2. Inside setupTest file, I had to add `import '@testing-library/jest-dom/vitest';`