# How do I get WebStorm to understand that Jest is in scope and stop suggesting I import other libraries that aren't Jest?

Tags: jestjs, webstorm

The behavior:

[image: WebStorm issue]

But I'm not using `node:test`, I'm using Jest. The `package.json` dev deps for that test file:

```json
"devDependencies": {
    // company specific imports removed
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "7.22.5",
    "@types/aws4": "1.11.2",
    "@types/jest": "29.5.3",
    "@types/node": "17.0.12",
    "dotenv": "16.3.1",
    "esbuild": "0.18.16",
    "esbuild-jest": "0.5.0",
    "eslint": "8.45.0",
    "jest": "29.6.1",
    "jest-mock-process": "2.0.0",
    "typescript": "5.1.6"
  }
```

It's like WebStorm doesn't understand that I am writing Jest tests, but Jest is right there in the deps. Sure, you can [import them explicitly](https://jestjs.io/docs/api) but I really shouldn't have to for WebStorm to figure this out. I've got 30 test files in this project and I'd prefer not to edit 30 files to fix this since it sure seems like a WebStorm issue. Looks like a bug to me but maybe there's an actual setting I'm missing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unresolved function or method "xxx" from Jest (23.5.0) in WebStorm (2018.2.3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186833/unresolved-function-or-method-xxx-from-jest-23-5-0-in-webstorm-2018-2-3)

Comment: kinda, but when I press that download button I get a message about a 403 error -- probably due to github changes. The node_modules directory for the code under test up above is in the list of libraries though.